# sampe application, one with hibernate hilo sequence, another without. will this create anu issue?

Tags: hibernate

We have an application where webservice uses hibernate and uses hilo(hibernate default sequence) method to create the primary key value. Ui uses ADF and it does not uses hilo method. it uses normal method.

Due to this web service creates something like 364616535,364616534,364616533,364616532 and UI create low values 36460688,36460687,36460686.

Now our application works fine. my question is when UI reaches service generated sequence value they will get exception right? duplicate value exception.

How to resolve this problem?

Note: i dont want to create next sequence for each insert statement in my webservice(hibernate).

Answer (score 0):

If the IDs of your UI-entered records were to overlap with the records created by the web service, then yes, you would get a Duplicate identifier or `NonUniqueObjectException` depending on your implementation.

Do you anticipate that more that 328 million records will be created through your UI? According to the numbers you posted, that is the gap between your respective sequences.

> web service creates something like
>   364616535,364616534,364616533,364616532 and UI create low values
>   36460688,36460687,36460686

I would recommend that both your webservice and your user interface do not use separate persistent entities (with difference sequences) to create records on the same table. Can you make the UI call the webservice to persist its data? That would solve your problem. If for whatever reason this is not possible, then I would at least configure both to use the same sequence, and start said sequence with an id higher than the max(id).